# Не работает форма на спйте

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, form

хотел бы узнать почему не работает форма на сайте, есть сайт http://vialuso.com/product/wordpress-pennant
При клике на купить в 1 клик вылезает модальное окно, хотел бы узнать почему данные не отправляются на почту? 
Форма написана на ajax и php

Answer (score 0):

Потому что это не форма

```
            <div class="modal-body-right">
                            <input id="form_email" type="email" placeholder="Введите email">
                            <input id="form_name" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя">
                            <input id="form_phone" type="phone" placeholder="Введите телефон">
                            <button class="form-button" type="submit" id="button_contacts">КУПИТЬ</button>
            </div>
```

этот блок должен находиться в теге form

да и кто му же у вас ошибки в js скриптах

красного не должно быть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]